# How can I stop a thread in oncheckedchanged?

Tags: android

Well I can start the thread when I press togglebutton to ON and it works fine, that thread is to start audiorecord and audiotrack.
But I cannot stop the thread when I put togglebutton OFF... because I cannot do thread.stop... What I want to do is just stop audiorecord and audiotrack... If there is any way to start/stop them w/o making thread will be also fine.
Also, as I cannot stop thread, when I do togglebutton ON - OFF - ON, it makes an error because can't start a thread 2 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stop()` method of Thread has been **Deprecated** (because it inherently unsafe) and java provides an alternative way to stop a Thread. Its a very simple approach, as described in this official link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Did you try making the `isRecording` variable global and then altering its state:

```
 isRecording = false;

 Thread thread;

 Runnable r = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    isRecording = true;
    android.os.Process
            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
    int bufferzize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferzize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
    if (arec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        arec.startRecording();
    if (atrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        atrack.play();
    while (isRecording) {
        arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
        atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }
}

};

tbs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbS);
tbs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isChecked) {
            thread = new Thread(r)
            thread.start();
            } else {
          isRecording = false;
          thread = null;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: yes i tried that and happens the same cuz it cannot stop the thread completely so when i do ON twice, there is an error

Comment: I am not sure how your program is working because you are using the `thread` variable, inside the `CheckedChangeListener`, even before declaring or initializing it. I have pasted a code snippet, maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: ye i tried it, does this work for you? for me it is not working

Comment: My last try at solving this problem :). Check the updated code I have pasted and hopefully it should run.

Comment: it can stop the thread but when i try to start the thread again after stopping it doesnt work, any idea?

Comment: i think thread = null made thread not working, how can i make it not null?

Comment: Are you getting any exception? I used a very simple approach of making a new thread when the condition `isChecked` is true else make it null.

Comment: ehm how can i make this ? if (thread is not started) thread.start; ? i only want it to start only once, but dunno what to put for thread is not started,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a variable and check in the function run if its state, like that :

```
   tbs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbS);
   boolean stopThread = false;
    tbs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isChecked) {

            thread.start();
            } else {
          stopThread = true;
        }

    }
});
      Thread thread = new Thread() {
public void run() {
    isRecording = true;
    android.os.Process
            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
    int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
    int bufferzize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 11025,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferzize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
    atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
    if (arec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        arec.startRecording();
    if (atrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
        atrack.play();
    while (isRecording) {
        arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
        atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }

    if(stopThread)
        return;
}

};
```

Comment: I already did that, but I think I used a static boolean to do it.

Comment: this doesnt stop thread, so the thread will be started 2 times

Answer (score 0):

I preffer Handlers in this case.

They have two features

```
Handler audioHandler = new Handler();

audioHandler.post(startAudio);   // Starts the operations

audioHandler.removeCallbacks(startAudio); //Stops the Operation
```

Following snippet will help you.

```
package org.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler audioHandler;
    private Runnable startAudio;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        audioHandler = new Handler();

        startAudio = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                isRecording = true;
                android.os.Process
                        .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
                int bufferzize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferzize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                if (arec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    arec.startRecording();
                if (atrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    atrack.play();
                while (isRecording) {
                    arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }

                audioHandler.post(startAudio);

            }
        };

        tbs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbS);
        tbs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {
                    audioHandler.post(startAudio);
                } else {
                    audioHandler.removeCallbacks(startAudio);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Will the audioHandler.post(startAudio); just after the run() method be ever called?

Comment: Yes.it under run method at last.So when execution reached end of run method.It again starts the loop.

Comment: ehmm this doesnt work for me at least :S the error is that could not get audio input source, which didnt happen before with threads :S

Comment: when i click the togglebutton, it works fine, the problem is that after clicking, i cannot click anything else, because everything stops but what i want to do works, any idea to fix that freezing?

Comment: @user1494252 are you performing any async operations on UI thread?

Comment: nono, i have put only what you have put, have no idea why it is freezing :S

Answer (score 0):

The thread is alive as long as `isRecording` is `true`. So you can have a `final StringBuilder` with which manipulates the value of `isRecording` as you need it.

```
  final StringBuilder isRecording=new StringBuilder("t");
Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                android.os.Process
                        .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
                int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                arec = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);
                int bufferzize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
                atrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 11025,
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferzize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                atrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
                if (arec.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    arec.startRecording();
                if (atrack.getState() == AudioTrack.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    atrack.play();
                while (isRecording.toString().equals("t")) {
                    arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }
            }

        };
    tbs = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbS);
        tbs.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isChecked) {
                    isRecording.replace(0,0,"t");
                    thread.start();
                    } else {
                isRecording.replace(0,0,"f")
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: isRecording.replace(0,"f") here it is saying that i need to put 1 more number like isRecording.replace(0, ?, "f") what to do?

Comment: also that cant stop the thread since isRecording only affects while()

Comment: @user1494252 : I have edited the replace function. As far as your thread is concerned, the thread is "running" only as long as the while loop is running. So if you come out of the while loop, your thread is over right?

Comment: Did you try this? this doesnt work still D: when i start thread twice there is an error

Comment: @user1494252 : No, I have not tried it. But I have used something like this. What is the error that you are getting when you run the thread twice?

Comment: the error is that if i run the thread twice, the app stops and says that thread cannot be runned when it is running, what i mean is that the thread doesnt stop completely when i try to

Comment: @user1494252 : okay.. do you have an idea of how much time the following lines take to execute on an average? -arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
            atrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);  Do you toggle very fast? the explanation that I can think of is that even though isRecording is false the two line of code take some time to execute and the thread dies only after these lines are executed and thn it knows that isRecording is false.

Comment: i have no idea how long does that take :P w8ed 20mins after toggled but doesnt work neither D: